# How to use native node_modules in react js (reactjs + electron) components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am trying to use native node_module i.e. "@pokusew/pcsclite" in reactjs application but it is not working . Can anyone help in this ?
Below is the error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: exists is not a function
   at Function.getRoot (bindings.js:202)
   at bindings (bindings.js:82)
   at Object.<anonymous> (pcsclite.js:4)
   at Object../node_modules/pcsclite/lib/pcsclite.js (pcsclite.js:160)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
   at fn (bootstrap:150)
   at Object../node_modules/pcsclite/index.js (index.js:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
   at fn (bootstrap:150)
   at Module.<anonymous> (App.css?4433:45)
   at Module../src/App.js (App.js:85)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784)
```

And below is the code that i am using in reactjs component where i am importing the pcsclite module in different ways one is by using import and another is by using require function

```
import pcsclite from '../node_modules/@pokusew/pcsclite'
var pcsc = pcsclite();
pcsc.on('reader', function(reader) {
    console.log('New reader detected', reader.name);
    reader.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Error(', reader.name, '):', err.message);
    });

    reader.on('status', function(status) {
        console.log('Status(', reader.name, '):', status);
        /* check what has changed */
        var changes = reader.state ^ status.state;
        console.log('changes(', changes, '):', status);
        if (changes) {
            if ((changes & reader.SCARD_STATE_EMPTY) && (status.state & reader.SCARD_STATE_EMPTY)) {
                console.log("card removed");/* card removed */
                reader.disconnect(reader.SCARD_LEAVE_CARD, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Disconnected');
                    }
                });
            } else if ((changes & reader.SCARD_STATE_PRESENT) && (status.state & reader.SCARD_STATE_PRESENT)) {
                console.log("card inserted");/* card inserted */
                reader.connect({ share_mode : reader.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED }, function(err, protocol) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Protocol(', reader.name, '):', protocol);
                        reader.transmit(new Buffer([0x00, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20]), 40, protocol, function(err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log('Data received', data);
                               // reader.close();
                               // pcsc.close();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you install it?

Comment: Can you show also the code that uses this library?

Comment: @MoshFeu updated the code. you can check .

Comment: @PrateekThapa installation was done.

Comment: try using absolute paths: `import pcsclite from "@pokusew/pcsclite"`

Comment: @PrateekThapa i tried that too but no use getting same error.

Comment: Can you check the content of this file `../node_modules/pcsclite/index.js` ?

Comment: @PrateekThapa thanks for your time. finally i found the solution and posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my above question. i have imported my native node_module in reactjs by window object . Below is the solution.

```
const electron = window.require('electron');
const pcsclite = electron.remote.require('@pokusew/pcsclite');
```